# How to create opened and closed levels

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create game with opened and closed levels. 
I have 10 levels. In each level is 10 underlevels. 1 level is open, other is close. In 1 level it is opened 9 underlevels. If I win any 7 underlevels, opens 10 underlevel. If i win 10 underlevel, opens second level with 9 underlevels.

How to make it with NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults?

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"openLevels"];
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                @"level 1-1", @"open",
                @"level 1-2", @"closed",
                @"level 1-3", @"closed",
                @"level 1-4", @"closed",
                @"level 1-5", @"closed",
                @"level 1-6", @"closed",
                @"level 1-7", @"closed",
                @"level 1-8", @"closed",
                @"level 1-9", @"closed",
                @"level 1-10", @"closed",nil];

        NSString *customerDict ;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:customerDict forKey:@"openLevels"];

       if ([[dict valueForKey:@"level 1-1"] isEqualToString:@"open" ]){

        }else{

            NSLog(@"not open");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each sublevel you want to know if it's open or closed when you start the app. To do that you can make a dictionary with each sublevel (level 1 sublevel 1 is level 1-1) and a value of either open or closed:

```
dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
           @"level 1-1", @"open", 
           @"level 1-2", @"open", 
           @"level 1-3", @"closed", 
           @"level 1-4", @"closed",  
           .....
           @"level 10-10", @"closed", nil];
```

Then you save it to NSUserDefaults:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:customerDict forKey:@"openLevels"];
```

When you start the app you read the saved dictionary to know what is opened and what is closed:

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"openLevels"];
```

Then when you create your levels you can just check if it's open or closed:

```
if [dict valueForKey:@"level 1-1"] isEqualToString: @"open" {
     //set level 1-1 as open
}
```

Comment: I'm just beginner, can you please give expanded answer. I didn't understand

Comment: I edited. Does it make more sense?

Comment: how can i connect this with my levelsItem ?

Comment: this is difficult for me. but I will try to make. thanks

Comment: Good luck. You will see it's very easy to do once you understand how NSDictionary works. Please give a checkmark if this works for you.

Comment: and how to change levelItemImage after level opening?

Comment: That is an entire other issue.

Comment: when i add screenshots can you more help me?

Comment: how connect this dict with my Items?

Comment: Have you even read my answer? The last part shows you how to test if a level is open.

Comment: it's work i chanched on -@"open", @"level 1-1". How change values when level is complete. how to make open level l-2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have this in a class - So you could archive that object and un archive it.  Here's a blog post that has a basic implementation

http://sam.roon.io/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding

You can take the data and store in the NSUserdefaults nothing fancy required. It's worth noting you can only archive Objects that conform to NSCoding

If you need to archive int or float then box them  @(1),  @(1.0) use NSValue for structs ;) http://nshipster.com/nsvalue/

Enjoy